# Magento .htaccess Removal of index.php from Store Urls

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I do not want my URLs on my Store to contain index.php. All my product pages can be accessed via addition of index.php and without it which is not good and I want to get rid of index.php from the urls.

For example, both of these urls display the same content, but I only want users to ever be directed to the second URL:
http://www.pudu.com.au/index.php/outback-mens-denim-cargo-shorts.html
&
http://www.pudu.com.au/outback-mens-denim-cargo-shorts.html

Likewise for content at the top level of the site:
http://www.pudu.com.au/index.php
&
http://www.pudu.com.au/

Comment: Downvoted for "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: When did we become the Magento help desk?

Answer (score 3):

Magento adds the system endpoint (index.php) to the URL path based on a configuration setting.  In the admin, navigate to System > Configuration. In the Web section, open the Search Engines Optimization group and set Use Web Server Rewrites to "Yes".  You'll need to flush the configuration cache and redindex URL rewrites thereafter.

Comment: Make sure the Magento provided .htaccess file is in the Magento root folder as well. It contains the rest of the url rewrite code.