# Magento URLs other than home page do not work without index.php

Tags: templates, magento, url-rewriting

My magento is installed on Ubuntu Linux under /var/www/magento .
This question looks like some of the questions in the archives
but is acutally somewhat different. When I installed Magento on
Ubuntu Linux I enabled Apache mod_rewrite URL rewrites.

When I go to http:// localhost/magento
my server rewrites the URL as http:// localhost/magento/
and displays the page. I then click on one of the links
in the navigation bar, let's say it's nav-bar item "foo".
Then magento takes me to:

http:// localhost/magento/foo.html

which displays a "Not Found" apache page.

I have to change the URL to ----->

http:// localhost/magento/index.php/foo.html

in order to display the page.

It is as though something is amiss in my mod_rewrite workings.

Thanks,

John Goche

CONFIGURATION: System -> Configuration -> (General ->) Web:

Use Web Server Rewrites: YES

Base URL: http:// localhost/magento

If I set "User Web Server Rewrites:" to NO, then the links
from my main page work fine, but see the page
http:// localhost/magento/index.php/foo.html
which displays the correct page, but whereas
the website works I don't like the URL. I
would like it to be http:// localhost/magento/foo.html
without the index.php bit, as this would also probably
be more SEO-friendly.

THanks,

John Goche

---

Update: I've tried uncommenting my artificial 127.0.1.1 IP address
which ubuntu had put in /etc/hosts and placing ther my real IP but
no luck. I still have exactly the same problem. And the URL inside
my browser is rewritten to http:// localhost / etc... whenver I
type 192.168.3.31, avalanche, or avalanche.com inside it.
I am still trying to figure out how to solve the problem
described above as this did not do it.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#127.0.1.1      avalanche

192.168.4.35    avalanche avalanche.com
```

When I restart Apache I get:

```
# service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.4.35 for ServerName
 ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.4.35 for ServerName
```

Not sure how to fix the original issue. I am testing on a local server.

---

I've even tried this solution and then restarted apache2, but no luck!

[How to remove index.php from URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/magento-how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls)

so placing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mymagento/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

does not work, even with RewriteBase /, it does not work.

---

OK, finally I managed to solve the probkem.
The file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
has the following directive set for all directories
defined within this file:

```
 AllowOverride None
```

For instance, for /var/www which is the default document root
set on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Linux system this file contains

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

which as far as I understand means that .htaccess files found in
this directory and all of its subdirectories will not be parsed.
To fix the problem it is sufficient to set:

```
AllowOverride All
```

meaning you will be able to override the server configuration directives
found in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (or /etc/apache2/httpd.conf which is
included therein).

One of the reasons AllowOverride is set to None by default could be that
it slows down the server and the other is for security reasons. This
directive should be set inside a  tag and the
latter ones can override the former. Another reason this is not
set by default is that having to parse .htaccess recursively
across the site each time a file in a directory path is
loaded can slow down the system and thus placing the
.htaccess stuff in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf when
possible is recommendable as it can cause an
increase in speed.

So place

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            #AllowOverride None
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

and run: service apache2 restart

is the solution.

Comment: I've tried all of the solutions I could find and they make absolutely no difference, even if I enable mod_rewrite in the admin panel, clear the cache, restart apache, and place the code in /var/www/mymagento/.htaccess (and go to http:// myip/mymagento/admin which gives the file not found whereas http:// myip/mymagento/index.php/admin works).

Comment: If you've managed to solve the problem, please don't add that to your question. Make it a separate answer instead. You are allowed and encouraged to do so.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you try:

```
RewriteBase /magento/
```

and not RewriteBase /mymagento/ because your url is http:// localhost/magento/

Does your apache virtual host allow to overwrite the config, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
<Directory /var/www/magento/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful, and is indeed the sought solution.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have [the appropriate .htaccess file](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/.htaccess) in your Magento root? Also, you may run into issues with `localhost`. It's advised to use 127.0.0.1 or to map dev domains in your hosts file.

Comment: Hello,

Yes I have this file. It got installed when I unzipped the magento source. However I am still having the problem. Do I need to adjust this file and if so then how? Perhaps I need to change the RewriteRule .* index.php [L] or something?

Comment: I've tried modifying my /etc/hosts file, but still have problems.

Answer (score 3):

Within the Magento configuration (accessed in the Magento Admin Panel through System > Configuration) there are some relevant settings that determine what the eventual Search Engine Friendly URL looks like.

```
Web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites
```

A setting which should always be turned on. If not "/index.php/" will be added to URL which is unnecessary and looks ugly. **To enable this option, you also need Apache mod_rewrite enabled in your hosting environment**.

```
Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations > Product URL Suffix
```

The default value here is ".html" which will be appended to each product URL. Some SEO-experts claim this is needed for better rating, other SEO-exports say it is not. For our MageBridge integration with Joomla! this setting needs to be empty.

```
Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations > Category URL Suffix
```

The same as above, but now categories.

```
Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations > Use categories path for product URLs
```

With this option enabled, the product URL will also include the category URL Keys. While it could be argued this causes duplicate content, product pages might also benefit from this because they become part of a bigger structure.

```
Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations > Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products
```

If you are really worried about duplicate content (which is not as bad as some people will tell you), then you can enable the canonical tag which tells search engines which page is leading once duplicate content has been detected.

```
Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations > Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories
```

The same as above, but for categories.

further reading on the matter http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/664-fixing-url-rewrites-with-magento

Comment: Thank you for all of this information, but I am still having the same problem. Web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites is set to Yes at the Global level, and I have # a2enmod rewrite which says Module rewrite already enabled. So where is the problem? I want to get rid of /index.php/ in the URLs!

Comment: Sounds like you need to get someone acquainted with Apache web server administration to help you troubleshoot why mod_rewrite is not functioning on your server. It really is as simple as turning on **Use Web Server Rewrites** once mod_rewrite is properly set up (flush cache and reindex URL Rewrite Index after changing and saving the setting). In your Magento root .htaccess and server config, you need to make sure the following are set in the proper places: `RewriteEngine On`, `AllowOverride All`, `Options +FollowSymLinks` and that `RewriteBase` is set to the proper directory.

Comment: like Fiasco Labs noted you now have to verify if mod_rewrite is properly configured and can be enabled through .htaccess

Comment: Thanks a lot and +1. The first option worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Enabling Apache rewrite module for wamp worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Tried almost all the solution from `.htaccess` to `database tweaks`. This one worked for me.! Thanks. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
Go to admin url of your site. 
Suppose,http://example.com/index.php/admin/

Go to 'System' menu from navigation and click on 'Configuration'.
Under the 'General' tab in the left, click on 'Web'.
Open the 'Search Engines Optimization' section by clicking on it.
Then set 'Use Web Server Rewrites' value to 'No'
```

Comment: Is there any formatting or additional context you can add to this answer to make it more thorough?

Answer (score 2):

It is a **mod_rewrite** issue. I'm running *Ubuntu* and had the same problem during setup of apache and magento for a store migration.

Change `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to contain

```
<VirtualHost ...>
...
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews   
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

thus **allowing rewrites** for `var/www` on the webserver.

To make apache process the rewrite rules from magentos .`htaccess` file(s),
**enabling** the rewrite module via

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and **restarting apache** via

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload 
//(not service apache2 restart)
```

solved the entire issue for me.

See http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Apache/mod_rewrite and
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Apache for a thorough explanation of how to set things up the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when transferring my live site into localhost. Finally i resolved it.

I have windows OS. So i used WAMP stack for my localhost. I have spent lot of time to retrieve all the URL and its content in my localhost by changing .htaccess file,modifying core_config_data table in DB but everything went wrong.

Finally i got a clue to enable rewrite_module in Apache server.
1. To enable it Click on the Wamp icon in the tray bar (WAMP->Apache->Apache modules-> and select rewrite_module).
2. Restart Wamp Server.
3. clear cache (optional i think) - Delete all the files in the var/cache folder

Make Sure you have .htaccess file in your root folder lets assume(localhost/magento/.htaccess). If you don't have you will not get the result.

Thats it.

I hope now u will able to retrieve all other pages and URL other than home and also u will not get 404 error page.