# Magento installation: getting rid of having to have that /index.php/ in the middle of URLs

Tags: magento, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magento URLs other than home page do not work without index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702708/magento-urls-other-than-home-page-do-not-work-without-index-php)

I have posted this question and browsed the archives but could get no
working solution, so I am posting this again:

[Magento URLs other than home page do not work without index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702708/magento-urls-other-than-home-page-do-not-work-without-index-php)

Hopefully someone on this site can help resolve this annoying issue,

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated,

John Goche