# SSL Error in Magento (404 Not Found)

Tags: .htaccess, magento, ssl, http-status-code-404

Some background info:
I am running the latest version of magento. My install is hosted on SiteGround and I have an addon domain linked to the magento folder as its root. I have webserver rewrites enabled, autoredirect to base url disabled. My unsecure domain is in the format http://www.domain.com/, my secure https://www.domain.com. I have secure url for frontend enabled and secure url for backend disabled.

My Problem:
Everything in the backend works wonderfully. However, in the frontend, the main page loads, but upon trying to login i get a 404 not found (as it is using the https:// secure domain). If i add alter the address to include index.php/ the page loads and the error goes away. I am pretty sure its a .htaccess issue, however I am not sure how to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
soliman

Comment: Is it resolved? I am using codeigniter and getting 404 error. Seems like htaccess issue but couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soliman, Have you checked if the options under System > Configuration > Web > Url Options | Search Engines | (Un)Secure are conform to what you want?

Comment: The settings are set as I mentioned above. I have add store code to url set to no, auto redirect to base url also set to no, and use web server rewrites set to yes.

Comment: I am not sure what can be causing it, I have tried all the troubleshooting guides online, and yet I still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I am using Apache 2.4 and Magento 1.9.X and had the same issue.
The fix for me was creating a .htacess file at the root website folder, where magento folders are (app, skin, media. etc) with the code below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://my-site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(admin|user)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [R=301,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

found it here: 
[How to remove index.php from URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls)