# Cannot access my magento admin after change in admin secure category "http" to "https://"

Tags: php, magento, web, admin

Cannot access my magento admin after change in admin secure category  "http" to "https://" this is the error: 404 Not Found The server can not find the requested page:  `EXAMPLE.COM/index.php/admin` (port 443)

Comment: Do you have enabled https on your server?

Comment: Currently I can not enter in  C Panel because now few hours my boss(at work) changed password and not yet sent me new password for C panel... Tomorrow I will receive the new password...

Comment: Just in FileZilla can acces my site...

Comment: Unfortunately we did not solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to PHPMYADMIN than you can restore the URL.
- Open your site database
- Search for the core_config_data table and click Browse.
- Locate the rows to edit : web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url

Thanks

Comment: I have made this in magento admin and after that i can't acces my magento admin:
Use HTTPS/SSL for all login pages:

HTTPS and SSL are the protocols used for web for the encryption of website data that sent from the browser to server and vice versa. 
By using the data in encrypted format, we can save our magento store from the hackers.
For the HTTPS/SSL security we have to follow the below steps:

Comment: Access the “System” tab from the main toolbar
    Choose “Configuration” from the drop down menu
    Click on the “Web” tab in the left.
    Then choose “Secure” in the main window
    Now change the Base URL of your store from http://… to https://… 
    Select “yes” for both “Use Secure URLs in Frontend" and "Use Secure URLs in Admin”. 
    click the “Save Config” button at the top of the page.

Comment: After make this changes in magento admin i can't acces my magento admin :(

Comment: I can not access to the admin page. The value of web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url from the table "core_config_data" is  http://localhost:8080/magento/.   How can I solve this???

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and is related to your `.htaccess` do you really have this file? and check if `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Comment: Come on help me pls ... :)

Comment: hey check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397232/ssl-error-in-magento-404-not-found?rq=1

Comment: My .htaccess look that:

Part 1
############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

Comment: PArt2       
############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Comment: Part3
############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

Comment: Part4 
############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

Comment: Part5
############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

Comment: Part6
############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>