# Rewrite Magento Admin URL /index.php/admin -> /admin

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2

My Store admin URL is for example: http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/admin

I want to Rewrite this URL as : http://www.mydomain.com/admin

I have also tried "Admin Rewrites" Magento Extension, But it couldn't Help.

Currently I can't work directly in live website as it may lead to big trouble, So I am working in LOCALHOST now.

How Can I Achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I do it with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls. Did you try it??

Comment: Hello, vbak, there are 6 answers in your reference link,
Can you say, about which answer you are talking about ?

Comment: Follow the below steps it will helps you.

step 1: Goto to your site root folder and you can find the htaccess file there.Open it on text editor and find the line #Rewrite Base/ magento. Just replace it with Rewrite Base/

step 2: Then goto your admin panel and enable the Rewrites(set yes for Use Web Server Rewrites). You can find it at System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization.

step 3: Then goto Cache management page (system cache management ) and refresh your cache and refresh to check the site.

Comment: Hello, vbak, there is only one .htaccess in my root folder of project.
But it is blank. When i write 'Rewrite Base/' in localhost gets 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: Download a fresh copy of magento installation and take the htacces file.And then replace the line.Or search about the htaccess file online

Comment: `RewriteBase /` one word, space, slash. Otherwise you will get a 500 error due to bad syntax. Also you need a `Options +FollowSymLinks` and `RewriteEngine On` prior to that and also your web server needs the Rewrite DSO module loaded. If the DSO module isn't loaded, you will still get a 500 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got my solution from this following Blog Link:

- [Magento Admin URL Rewrite - Set /index.php/admin to /admin](https://magentowebmaster.blogspot.in/2013/11/magento-admin-url-rewrite-set.html) (Javascript required)

### Admin Rewrites (Magento Extension)

The just linked blog-post is referencing and explaining the usage of a Magento Extension called [*Admin Rewrites* (Magento Extension)](https://github.com/clockworkgeek/Magento-Admin-Rewrites).

The extension itself is available on Github and can be installed via *Magento Composer Installer* and/or *Modman*:

- https://github.com/clockworkgeek/Magento-Admin-Rewrites

Alternatively it is also listed in [Magento Conect](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-rewrites.html) ([Magento Conect 2.0 Key](http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Clockworkgeek_Adminrewrite)).

Answer (score 2):

Another method of doing this does involve modifying a core Magento file (which is a big no, no for upgrading purposes) but works all the same: http://www.code007.ro/magento-how-to-remove-index-php-from-admin-url/