# Magento login page and register page doesnt charge error 500

Tags: php, magento

Hello i have a problem with magento url login pages and register page, i have changed on database table  `core_config_data` the default url for the new domain, now it makes a problem because and i cant enter to login url pages and register here i put the live links, thanks! i hope any can help me, i dont know why it doesnt work, i need make a other changes? thanks
http://masluzz.panamerik.net/customer/account/login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sara it is rewrite issue,if  you try this using  index.php  then http://masluzz.panamerik.net/index.php/customer/account/login open properly.

check htaccess rewite is working or not
add code in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

more details [How to remove index.php from URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls)