# Unable to remove index.php from url magento On VPS hosting

Tags: apache, magento, seo, vps

I am using the VPS hosting.

I have create a virtual server under `/var/www/html` , Now at this I have migrate my Magento site.

If I am make changes in `.htaccess` file to remove `index.php` from url it is not working. I have tried from the Magento admin panel Use Web Server `Rewrites -> Yes` , it also not work.

`Mod_rewrite` is also enable.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Issue resolved. There was the problem that in the particular store configuration index.php was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As you already set `Web Server Rewrites` to `Yes`. Please make sure `Base Secure URL` and `Base Unsecure URL` not contain `index.php` Ex:

Base URL must be like `http://www.example.com/` instead of `http://www.example.com/index.php/`

Comment: Hi.. Pankaj... I am using the base url without index.php... All the same data is proper working on the my Godaddy hosting.

Comment: okay .. please follow answer on these two posts http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/remove-index-php-from-the-magento-url-gives-404-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls here mentioned all possible cases